# How do I loop it for multiple List in one object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, dataset

I have a dataset which stores the data fetched from the DB.

My data set looks like following:

```
Id     EmpId     Questions
 1        6       abcdefgh
 2        6       kjkjlkjj
 3        6       yiuyuiyi
 4        6       kljkljkl
```

I have to loop through dataset and assign the values to my class which looks like following

```
   Public class MyClass
      Public Property Id As Integer = 0
      Public Property EmpId As Integer = 0
      Public Property Question As List(of String)
   End Class
```

How do i loop through dataset and create one object and fetch multiple questions in to the 'Question' Property as List(assign to MyClass object).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want one MyClass for each EmpID with a list of questions for that EmpID? BTW, DataSets hold DataTables. It is a data table that you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot store anything in a `dataset` rather than a `DataTable`, within the `DataTable`, there are data. So, to simplify the question, it should rather be

> How to loop through a DataTable inside a DataSet ?

The answer is very simple.

**Firstly, grab the DataTable**

```
Dim Dt as DataTable = dataset.Table("table name")
```

**Now iterate through the DataTable**

```
For Each Row in Dt
 Dim value1 as String = Row(0) ' Here 0 is the column index,change it as required
Next
```

Now coming back to the 2nd part of your question :

> assign the values to my class …

Well, firstly, you need to create a `List` of the class `MyClass`.

```
Dim myClassList as New Lsit(Of MyClass)
```

**Now, within the loop, you can do :**

```
For Each Row in Dt
 Dim Class1 as New MyClass
 class1.Id= Convert.ToInt32(Row(0)) ' Here 0 is the column index,change it as required
 '''assign other values as well(if required)
 myClassList.Add(Class1)
Next
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @zack. It really helped :)

Comment: @Santosh , you are most welcome.. I hope to help you in future as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
Public Function ReturnQuestions() As List(Of MyClass)
    Dim questions As New List(Of MyClass)()
    Using ds As DataSet = GetData("select Id, EmpId, Questions from table")
        //check if populated
        If (ds IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (ds.Tables.Count > 0) AndAlso (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0)
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                questions.Add(New MyClass(ds(0), ds(1), ds(2)))
            Next
        End If
    End using
    Return questions
End Function
```

For each loop over your dataset.tables.rows (checking if not nothing first)

Then inside the loop do a myList.Add(new MyClass(ds(0),ds(1),..))

At the end you’ll have a list parsed from your DS.  There are multiple ways to craft the inside part of the for loop if you have any questions reach out

Comment: What is myList here? can you please explain with a dummy code.

Comment: An answer with no explanation, no formatting and nevertheless, useless

Comment: sorry all was on mobile - correct answer w/ example

Comment: Inside of the Constructor of MyClass you can set each value.  If you don't want to use a constructor, use the With syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement